# How can I monitor a virtual serial port in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, serial-port

I need to listen to everything that goes (both directions) through a virtual serial port on Windows 7 64bit.

I do not need to send anything, just monitor the communication for debugging purposes.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from Sysinternals

It allows to see all reads and writes made by a process.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work for 64bit OSs.